# Jenkins Folder Edit Default All View

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

You can change the default view of Jenkins itself by creating a new view and going into the system config to point to this new view.  I would like to do the same within a folder to have all folders automatically have specific view.

My use case here is to add/remove columns globally that apply to everything.  It seems like the folders plugin manages views internally and don't have access to the normal global view tabs that you can see when not in a folder.

If there is no way to change the default, does anyone know if there is a way to create a new view that all users can access across folders?

Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried to create a new view by clicking the + button next to All on the dashboard.  I set this view to be configured as a list view with the columns that I need, but none of the folders have access to this new view and it seems that the folders plugin doesn't respect the system default.